# Who or what is the northwest shop in Flotsam?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Following the shop icons on the map, I found:

- the dwarven Blacksmith
- the bookseller across the street from him (Einar Gausler)
- a stall selling alchemy components nearby
- Sendler in Lobinden village
- woman selling herbs in Lobinden village
- Cedric

Meanwhile, on the map I see an icon for a store to the north-west, near a man cooking a cauldron of stew.  When I try to enter the building where I see that icon, there's a door that doesn't activate at all on the side facing the water, and a locked door facing the street.

This is the north-western most shop icon on the map, and also near the merchant you negotiate for the Kayran reward.

Is this some sort of secret store, or am I just missing an obvious entrance somewhere?

Comment: Stew in Lobinden, or Flotsam?

Comment: In Flotsam.  Also near the platform with crates and lumber.  Nearest to where you first enter the town at the beginning of Chapter 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This vendor is part of the Mysterious Merchant DLC ([see this thread in the GOG forums](http://www.gog.com/en/forum/the_witcher_2/mysterious_merchant_dlc_locations_in_all_acts/post1)). This DLC seems to be exlusive to copies of the game sold by Gamestop. If your copy is bought from somewhere else as mine is, you're still seeing the vendor icon but you can't get to the mysterious merchant.

Comment: @Damien Update, you can now get the DLC with patch 1.2. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23881/whats-the-deal-with-the-witcher-2-dlc

Comment: @Matthew Read, Thanks for the tip.  I'm already past chapter 1, but I'm sure I'll replay it in the future.

Comment: @Damien the vendor is also present in the later chapters